# infinite scroll doesn't stop when contents finish

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails-3.2, infinite-scroll

hi am having a problem with infinite scroll functionality, when all the contents have been displayed it still continues to scroll (strange behavior). i am looking for a way to stop the infinite scroll when all contents are displayed

here is my code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
(function () {
   var page = 1,
   loading = false,
   finish = false;


function nearBottomOfPage() {
return $(window).scrollTop() > $(document).height() - $(window).height() - 200;
 }

 function finish() {
  finish = true;

}
 $(window).scroll(function () {
  if (loading) {
   return;
 }
if (nearBottomOfPage() && !finish) {
  loading = true;
  $('#loader').show();
  page++;
  $.ajax({
    url: '/office?page=' + page,
    type: 'get',
    dataType: 'script',
    success: function () {
      $('#loader').hide();
      loading = false;
    }
  });
  }
});
}());
```

i have bee working on this days now....please heeeeeeeeeeelllllllllpppppp :(

Comment: You are not callig finish() in your script. Add an attribute from your backend to indicate when there are no pages left :)

Comment: hmmmm i am wondering how to specify when there are no pages left...any suggestions.

Comment: Well, how do you do the pagination ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try unbinding it from window object.
Suppose your last page reached then use this function

```
$(window).unbind('scroll');
```

Comment: where do i place this $(window).unbind('scroll');...is it after the nearBottomOfPage function or inside it...pls can u show me an example...thanks

Comment: yes you have to place it after your last page check condition

Comment: hmmm but it seems my code doesn't have that last page condition...can you help me out

Answer (score 0):

**Hello Folks,**
I just encountered the same issue! After hours of searching online and trying many solutions, I came up with this solution.

**Search in `infinite-scroll.js` file for that variable:**

`t.children()`

**Then change it's value from (1==1) to (0==1) as follows:**

`case"append":var l=t.children();if(1==l.length)return this._error("end");`

**To:**

`case"append":var l=t.children();if(0==l.length)return this._error("end");`

Now, when you reach the end of posts, the **FinishedMsg** should appear.

Hope this helps.